# Equivalent to master pages in ASP Classic

Tags: templates, asp-classic, ssi

Is it possible to build some kind of master page with Classic ASP **without** frames or `iframe`s?

I’m wondering if there is a way to include content pages in the main page like [ASP.NET master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) do. From what I have researched, ASP Classic does support inclusion of other ASP/HTML pages into a page, but the value put into this `include` means the function cannot be dynamic.

Comment: It's not quite clear but is it conditional includes you're after? Because this is not really possible `<%If true Then%> <!--#include file="A.asp"--> <%Else%> <!--#include file="B.asp"--> <%End If%>`

Comment: Wow.  I came here to find out where the magical code was on the classic ASP page I'm working on that includes a header.  I didn't realize that the `<!--#include header.asp-->` "comments" were actually directives. /facepalm.  Microsoft once again wins the "dumbest code concept" prize...

Comment: The "include" directive is "Server Side Includes" syntax. Microsoft did not invent it, they just support it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could just create functions (say, a `Header()` function and a `Footer()` function) which do nothing but output some set of markup.  Those functions can take parameters too, and be called conditionally.  It's not quite the same as a Master page, but it sounds like it accomplishes what you are trying to do.  You would have an `<!--#include file="headerfooter.asp"-->` on each page, and each page would call `Header()` & `Footer()`.

Or you can just use `<!--#include file="header.asp"-->` at the top and `<!--#include file="footer.asp"-->` at the bottom of each page too.  I've seen both approaches.

If you are looking for the reverse, that is, a single template page which calls individual pages in it's "middle" section, then that's not really something you can do easily with ASP classic.  It's a fundamental difference in approach: ASP.NET has a concept of a control tree, events, etc, while ASP Classic is essentially just a script that runs top to bottom.

Answer (score 8):

This idea is from [Classic ASP Master Pages | Godless Code](http://godlesscode.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/classic-asp-master-pages/). I’ve transcribed the code in images on that page, extended its example a bit, and also explored the limitations of this technique.

The idea is that each page has only one Server-Side Include (one `<!--#include file="" -->` call). The single inclusion is a master template file, which you could name `master.asp`. The master page calls custom subroutines on each page in place of each content area. Each child page defines those subroutines with `Sub`, with content unique to that child page.

`master.asp`

```asp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><% Title() %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% BodyContent() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

`aboutUs.asp`

```asp
<!--#include file="master.asp" -->

<% Sub Title %> About Us <% End Sub %>

<% Sub BodyContent %>
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>
        We do things!
    </p>
<% End Sub %>
```

That turns into this HTML when you visit `aboutUs.asp` on an IIS server:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> About Us </title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>
        We do things!
    </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

However, this approach does not allow nesting:

`subtemplate.asp`

```asp
<div class="innerLogo <% LogoSide() %>">
    <% LogoImg() %>
</div>
```

`template_user.asp`

```asp
<!--#include file="master.asp" -->

<% Sub Title %> Our Logo <% End Sub %>

<% Sub BodyContent %>

    <!--#include file="subtemplate.asp" -->

    <% Sub LogoSide %> leftside <% End Sub %>

    <% Sub LogoImg %>
        <img src="img/about.png" alt="About" />
    <% End Sub %>

<% End Sub %>
```

This will not work, because nested `Sub`s are a syntax error:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ea'
>
> Syntax error
>
> /template_user.asp, line 9
>
> ```
> Sub LogoSide
> ^
> ```

Since nesting is not allowed, this templating system is, in effect, a one-time solution. If your individual pages’ subroutines become too unwieldy, you can’t use this technique again. So when using this technique, you should carefully choose where to carve out your set of templates in order to provide the best balance between flexibility and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ness.

Comment: "This will not work, because nested Subs are a syntax error" -- This is true only when using VBScript. You can replace the subs with JavaScript functions (along with a language declaration at the top of the child page), and nest all you want. People often forget that JavaScript is the better language solution in Classic ASP (probably because it's documented nowhere).

Answer (score 4):

Rory wrote a great example for master pages in Classic ASP, but demonstrated that the "master page" approach had its limitations because Subs cannot be nested.

However, for the sake of demonstration, and because JavaScript in Classic ASP has hardly any documentation anywhere on the Internet, here's the same example that fails in ASP VBScript but *won't* fail in ASP JavaScript.

`master.asp`

```asp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><% Title() %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% BodyContent() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

`subtemplate.asp`

```asp
<div class="innerLogo <% LogoSide() %>">
    <% LogoImg() %>
</div>
```

`template_user.asp`

```asp
<%@ Language= "Javascript" %> 
<!--#include file="master.asp" -->

<% function Title() { %> About Us <% } %>

<% function BodyContent() { %>

    <!--#include file="subtemplate.asp" -->

    <% function LogoSide() { %> leftside <% } %>

    <% function LogoImg() { %>
        <img src="img/about.png" alt="About" />
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

It works! here are the juicy results:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> About Us </title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="innerLogo  leftside ">
      <img src="img/about.png" alt="About" />
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Remember, JavaScript, even the ECMAScript 3 version in Classic ASP, is often way more powerful and expressive than the VBScript engine that was favoured and heavily promoted by Microsoft. If you ever have to use Classic  ASP, use JavaScript!

Answer (score 3):

One of the ugliest problems in classic ASP is that `#includes` always happen, so putting two includes in an `if`-`then`-`else` construct always includes both – even though you only see the output that applies to your conditional value.

Even when includes work, they don't give you the result you're really looking for, which is to select a template or skin “on the fly”.

One way to handle this situation is to use a template engine such as KudzuASP that surpasses the traditional `#include` methodology.  Here is a very simple example:

```html
<!-- An HTML Template -->
<html>
<head><title><!--[Replace|PageTitle]-->PageTitle<!--[/Replace]--></title></head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" callspacing="2" width="640">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><!--[HeaderContent/]--></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="160"><!--[LeftColumnContent/]--></td>
    <td><!--[MainContent/]--></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><!--[FooterContent/]--></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the ASP code looks like this:

```vbs
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<!-- #include file="./KudzuASP/_kudzu.asp" -->
<%
Dim PageTitle : PageTitle = "This is a Master Page"

'
' Create the template engine
'
Dim T_ENGINE
Set T_ENGINE = New CTemplateEngine

T_ENGINE.PutValue "PageTemplate", PageTemplate
T_ENGINE.SetHandler "HeaderContent", New CTXHeaderContent
T_ENGINE.SetHandler "LeftColumnContent", New CTXLeftColumnContent
T_ENGINE.SetHandler "MainContent", New CTXMainContent
T_ENGINE.SetHandler "FooterContent", New CTXFooterContent

'
' Custom Tage Handlers
'
Class CTXHeaderContent
    Public Sub HandleTag(vNode)
        vNode.Engine.ContentAppend "Header"
    End Sub
End Class

Class CTXLeftColumnContent
    Public Sub HandleTag(vNode)
        vNode.Engine.ContentAppend "Left<br/>Content"
    End Sub
End Class

Class CTXMainContent
    Public Sub HandleTag(vNode)
        vNode.Engine.ContentAppend "Main<br/>Content"
    End Sub
End Class

Class CTXFooterContent
    Public Sub HandleTag(vNode)
        vNode.Engine.ContentAppend "Footer"
    End Sub
End Class

'
' Evaluate the template
'
T_ENGINE.ParseFile Server.MapPath("./MasterPage.html")
T_ENGINE.EvalTemplate
%>
```

The template engine makes calls to your custom objects defined in the hosting ASP code page when the appropriate tags are processed.  The function members of your custom classes have direct access to the hosting page and its variables and methods, as well as the template engine’s object hierarchy.  In other words, the template is driving the output and the hosting ASP page during output.

This beats the include mechanism hands down, because the template engine can dynamically select which HTML template to process at runtime, and it can dynamically include libraries of custom tag handlers using the built in `<!--[import/]-->` tag.

UPDATE 2016.01.13: I have open sourced this project and you can find the latest code maintained at this address: https://github.com/Mumpitz/KudzuASP

Comment: Sadly, the [site of KudzuASP’s author](http://www.andrewfriedl.com/downloads/), where you could download KudzuASP, seems to be [down](http://isup.me/www.andrewfriedl.com/downloads/) now, as is the [old download site](http://kudzu.trilogicllc.com/webray/QuikPage.asp?topic=Downloads). But I was able to find an [old version of the library and example pages](http://code.google.com/p/allsoft/source/browse/trunk/trunk/Web_Resources/KudzuASP), and an [old article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22348/KudzuASP-Introduction-to-Templating-with-KudzuASP) about KudzuASP.

Answer (score 0):

I just use a Default.asp page with html, then put my code in the content area.

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="topNav"> <!--begin top Nav-->
                <ul> 
                    <!--Be sure that all links are like this href="?page=contentPageEx"-->
                    <li><a href="?page=home">Home</a></li> 
                </ul>   
            </div> <!--end top Nav-->

            <div id="content">
                   <%
                        Dim default
                        default= Request.QueryString 
                        If default= "" Then 
                        Server.execute "includes/home.html"
                        Else 
                        Server.execute "includes/" & request("page")  & ".html"
                        end if 
                    %>   
            </div>  


            <div id="botNav"> <!--begin bot Nav-->
                <ul> 
                  <li><a href="?page=home">Home</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </div> <!--end Bot Nav-->

         </body>
</html>
```

Then I put all my content into an includes file with html pages.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />

            <!--Search engines use this title ect...-->
            <title>Hello SEO! This is a content page!</title>
            <!--Can be styled independently-->
            <style>
              p {
                    color: #0094ff;   
                }  
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
         <p>Hello World!</p>   
        </body>
    </html>
```