# ASP classic .NET How do I inherit a layout

Tags: html, .net, asp-classic

I want to create a simple website in ASP classic.
I would like to create ex. a navigator which stay the same for all pages. I did something similar using flask. There I could create a "layout.html" which all other pages extended and could insert html code directly to it.

Layout.html

```
... some html code
{% block column_mid %}
{% endblock %}
... some html code
```

Index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block column_mid %}
<div id="column_mid">
 <h1>Heading</h1>
 <br>
 <div class="column">
  <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you are into ancient tech, could [frameset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) be a solution? Do note the warning, however

Comment: Classic ASP supports the include file directive, and most users do something like `<!-- #include file="header.asp" -->` near the top of the page and `<!-- #include file="footer.asp" -->` at the bottom.  There are ways of creating a full template though - here's a question which covers it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837211/equivalent-to-master-pages-in-asp-classic